# Django settings

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, settings

In my project (based on Django) I need a custom option in order to switch on/off some functionality in my view.

```
if (FLAG):
    .....
else:
    .....
```

As I know, if I set this variable in settings.py I wouldn't have imported it from  settings.py, because settings.py is not a module and I need import settings.py as a whole object. What else can I use as a setting variable in Django?

Comment: What do you mean? Have you tried `import myapp.settings`?

Comment: Can you explain which functionality, how much you tried ?

Comment: @Wtower the problem is that I can't do: from myapp.settings import FLAG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `request.session`. It stores the values as dictionary

```
request.session['flag'] = True    #or False as per your requirement
...
if (request.session['flag']):
    ...
else:
    ...
```

When you are done using this variable, just delete it using

```
del request.session['flag']
```

Answer (score 4):

You can import as you wish like

```
from django.conf import settings
```

**settings.py**

```
FUNCTIONALITY_A = True
```

Then in **views.py**

```
If settings.FUNCTIONALITY_A == True
    #do your stuff
```

**Otherwise**

```
from yourproject import settings
```

Answer (score 1):

Create custom setting `YOUR_SETTING`, place in settings.py. In your views you can use settings like this

```
from django.conf import settings
...
# in view
if settings.YOUR_SETTING:
    # do something
```

[More info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code).